# Python opencv could not open image and no error

Tags: python, opencv

Mac + pycharm

code like this:

```
img = cv2.imread(images[0])
cv2.imshow('Image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**No error, Pycharm just keeps running it, after running a few minutes I have to stop by myself.**

BTW the image is only 16KB

try matplotlib and it works.

```
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

So no file error

Comment: Weird.  This actually looks like it should work.  Try creating a window explicitely and seeing if it changes anything:  `cv2.namedWindow('Image'); cv2.imshow('Image',img)`

Comment: @Jeremiah   Hi, thanks for applying. Have tried, nothing happened but it ends running pretty quick.... at least I dont have to wait hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your image display code to this:

```
img = cv2.imread(images[0])
cv2.imshow('Image',img)
if cv2.waitKey(0) == 27   #waits for the ESC key to be pressed
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```